# Perform an action once location accuracy reaches certain level in Swift

Tags: swift, cllocation, swift2

I've been searching for an answer to this for some time, but I can't believe I'm the first person who ever wanted to do it. Perhaps I'm looking in the wrong places!

My question is, how do I wait until a user's location has reached a certain accuracy level before performing an action? Essentially, I want to write a conditional statement which runs once the horizontalAccuracy and verticalAccuracy are at a good enough level to give me an accurate enough latitude and longitude.

Up until this point I have been looping through the long and lat until it no longer reads 0.0,0.0 and saving that data, but I don't think it's a particularly safe way of doing it as 0.0,0.0 is a genuine coordinate. Nor does it mean I get accurate results (even if it doesn't find 0.0,0.0 first), as the location takes a bit of warming up before it finally narrows down to an accuracy I'd be happy with. Nothing I've tried searching for has helped in the slightest.

If anyone could point me in the direction of an article/example/documentation, that would be great.

I'm using Swift 2. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding but are you basically asking how to check if a user is within a certain distance?

Comment: I'm more interested in the accuracy. I don't want to save coordinates if it's not accurate enough. For example, when tracking a route, the first few points are all over the place before it finally settles on an accurate location.